# ASP.NET Validation not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, validation, jquery-validate

I made a registration form , add to it some validation but they not being targeted/fired , am not sure what's wrong , also it seems to work fine on Internet Explore but not on firefox:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="Register" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            width: 143px;
            text-align: right;
        }
        .auto-style3 {
            width: 280px;
        }
        .auto-style4 {
            font-size: x-large;
            text-align: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="auto-style4">

        Registeration</div>
        <table class="auto-style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">Username:</td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbUserName" runat="server"  Width="277px" MaxLength="16"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbUserName" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbUserName" ErrorMessage="4 - 16 Characters!" ForeColor="Red" MaximumValue="16" MinimumValue="4" Type="Integer"></asp:RangeValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">Password:</td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbPassword" runat="server" Width="277px" MaxLength="16"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbPassword" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbPassword" ErrorMessage="4 - 16 Characters!" ForeColor="Red" MaximumValue="16" MinimumValue="4" Type="Integer"></asp:RangeValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">Confirm Password:</td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbConfPassword" runat="server" Width="277px" MaxLength="16"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbConfPassword" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbConfPassword" ErrorMessage="4 - 16 Characters!" ForeColor="Red" MaximumValue="16" MinimumValue="4" Type="Integer"></asp:RangeValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">Email:</td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbEmail" runat="server" Width="277px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbEmail" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">First Name:</td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tb1stName" runat="server" Width="277px" MaxLength="16"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tb1stName" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tb1stName" ErrorMessage="4 - 16 Characters!" ForeColor="Red" MaximumValue="16" MinimumValue="4" Type="Integer"></asp:RangeValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">Second Name:</td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tb2ndName" runat="server" Width="277px" MaxLength="16"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tb2ndName" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tb2ndName" ErrorMessage="4 - 16 Characters!" ForeColor="Red" MaximumValue="16" MinimumValue="4" Type="Integer"></asp:RangeValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">Age:</td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbAge" runat="server" Width="277px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbAge" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">Gender:</td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="dlGender" runat="server" Width="277px">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Select Gender</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server" ControlToValidate="dlGender" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">Secret Question1:</td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="dl1stQ" runat="server" Height="24px" Width="277px">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Select Question</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>What is your Favourite Car Manufacturer?</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>What is your Favourite Food?</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>What is your Favourite Video Game?</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>What is your Favourite Drink?</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>What is your Favourite Brand?</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" ControlToValidate="dl1stQ" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">Answer:</td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbAnswer" runat="server" Width="277px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator10" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbAnswer" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">Secret Question2:</td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="dlQ2" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="277px">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Select Question</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>What is your Favourite Sports Team?</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Who is your Favourite Singer?</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Who is your Favourite Actor?</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Who is your Favourite Actress?</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Who is your favourite Sports Player?</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator11" runat="server" ControlToValidate="dlQ2" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">Answer:</td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbAnswer2" runat="server" Width="277px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator12" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbAnswer2" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">Secret Question3:</td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="dlQ3" runat="server" Width="277px">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Select Question</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>What is your mother Maiden Name?</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Where were you born?</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>What was your first best friends Name?</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Who was your first kiss?</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator13" runat="server" ControlToValidate="dlQ3" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">Answer:</td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbAnswer3" runat="server" Width="277px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator14" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbAnswer3" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that is incredibly vague

Comment: any JavaScript error messages when "not working" in Firefox?

Answer (score 4):

Can you check you console in your firebug for any JavaScript errors? 
Also you can try to put a validation group for you validators and button.

Answer (score 3):

You can try calling `Page.Validate();` in the code behind on load. You can also set the property of a button `CausesValidation` to true.  By default the page doesn't validate before it loads.  It should validate after you click a button if cause validation is true.  You can also manually force validation by calling Page.Validate()

Comment: Server-side validation is a MUST! You cannot rely only on client-side validation, as it is way too easy to circumvent. Client-side validation is nice, because it is almost immediate feedback, but you MUST always validate the data the server receives.

Answer (score 2):

Which type of error message shown in browser or why Visual Studio Fire? You did not mention it.

I think your error message is like this

```
WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).
```

Ok, you may try to use this bellow section in web config for validation control. I hope it will solve your validation control problem.

```
  <appSettings>
    <!--
      For Validation Control
      -->
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
```

If the problem continues, attach this script in your ASPX page behind the `<head>` tag.

```
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js
```

"jquery(case-sensitive)" this message should not be shown again.

Answer (score 0):

make the same Validation Group Of all your text and Add button and Validation

```
 ValidationGroup="AAA"
```

and add the code to your save button:

```
 If (Page.IsValid) Then
    YOURSQL.Insert()
 'or ur code here'
  End If
```